# Django - Working with Forms. What does .save() do?

Tags: django

Hello i am new to django and this forms in django is really hard to understand. This is my code below

### forms.py

```
class VideoForm(forms.Form):
videoname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
videodesc = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

### vrform.html

```
<form class="form-signin" method="GET" action="{% url 'vrform' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Add your video request here</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{formKey.videoname}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{formKey.videodesc}}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.homepage,name = 'home'),
path('request', views.form,name = 'form'),
]
```

### views.py

```
def vrform(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    formValue = VideoForm(request.GET)

    if formValue.is_valid():
        new_req = Video(videotitle=request.GET['videoname'], videodesc=request.GET['videodesc'])
        new_req.save()
        return redirect('index')

return render(request, 'videorequest/vrform.html', {'formKey': formValue})
```

Someone please explain me this views.py file
what is this .save() method do? does it save in the database?

When it encounters the line return redirect('index'). Then the next return will never execute right? It will never go to vrforms.html right?  These might be silly doubts because i an new to django sorry. Please someone clear my doubts.

Comment: Every ModelForm also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. For more check the offcial doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: @BidhanMajhi Ya it creates and saves the database object. At which step does it exactly saves in the database?

Answer (score 0):

`.save()` is saving the value in your database. When you call `new_req.save()`, it is just saving your data to DB.

As you are using `ModelForm` so you don't need to initialize the `Video` model. Just use like this:

```
if formValue.is_valid():
     formValue.save()
     return redirect('index')
```

`formValue.save()` means your form will save the value to your declared `model` in `Meta` class.